# Which parameters are best to POST a JSONObjetc that contains a JSONArray with retrofit on android studio?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, woocommerce-rest-api

Building a new android project, it has been tried to write data inside a JSON from a woocoomerce REST API web service using retrofit.

These are the POJO classes used to contain the data that is to be send, please note that lineitem is contained inside Pedido:

```
public class Pedido {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("date_created")
@Expose
private String dateCreated;
private String dateModified;
private int customerId;
private String total;
@SerializedName("customer_note")
@Expose
private String customerNote;
private String dateCompleted;
private String datePaid;
@SerializedName("line_items")
@Expose
private ArrayList<LineItem> line_items;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}


public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}


public String getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}


public void setDateCreated(String dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}


public String getDateModified() {
    return dateModified;
}


public void setDateModified(String dateModified) {
    this.dateModified = dateModified;
}


public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}


public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}


public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}


public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}


public String getCustomerNote() {
    return customerNote;
}


public void setCustomerNote(String customerNote) {
    this.customerNote = customerNote;
}


public String getDateCompleted() {
    return dateCompleted;
}


public void setDateCompleted(String dateCompleted) {
    this.dateCompleted = dateCompleted;
}


public String getDatePaid() {
    return datePaid;
}


public void setDatePaid(String datePaid) {
    this.datePaid = datePaid;
}


public List<LineItem> getLineItems() {
    return line_items;
}


public void setLineItems(ArrayList<LineItem> line_items) {
    this.line_items = line_items;
}
```

}

```
public class LineItem {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
private String itemname;
@SerializedName("quantity")
@Expose
private int quantity;
private double price;
private String total;

public int getidprod(){return id;}

public void setIdprod(int id){this.id = id;}

public String getitemname(){return itemname;}

public int getQuantity(){return quantity;}

public void setQuantity(int quantity){this.quantity = quantity;}

public double getPrice(){return price;}

public String gettotal(){return total;}
```

}

Next, the Endpoint method that is used to POST the data (here's were the problem lies) which is only creating empty registers

```
@POST("orders"+ ConstantesAPI.ACCES_TOKEN)
Call<Pedido> Crearpedido(@Body Pedido pedido);
```

And Finally this is how the method instances is been called:

```
pedido.setCustomerId(id_cliente_np);
    pedido.setDateCreated(df.format(c.getTime()));
    pedido.setLineItems(lineitems);

Call<Pedido> peticionpedido = pedidoapi.Crearpedido(pedido);
    peticionpedido.enqueue(new Callback<Pedido>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Pedido> call, Response<Pedido> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pedido de cliente:  "+ pedido.getcustomerId() +"   Realizado con Éxito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Pedido> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: el Pedido no pudo ser realizado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

The JSON response is this where "customer_id" is 0 and no "line_items" are posted:

```
{

"id": 261,
"parent_id": 0,
"status": "pending",
"order_key": "wc_order_58a26745d6579",
"number": 261,
"currency": "MXN",
"version": "2.6.7",
"prices_include_tax": false,
"date_created": "2017-02-14T02:11:17",
"date_modified": "2017-02-14T02:11:17",
"customer_id": 0,
"discount_total": "0.00",
"discount_tax": "0.00",
"shipping_total": "0.00",
"shipping_tax": "0.00",
"cart_tax": "0.00",
"total": "0.00",
"total_tax": "0.00",
"billing": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": "",
    "email": "",
    "phone": ""
},
"shipping": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": ""
},
"payment_method": "",
"payment_method_title": "",
"transaction_id": "",
"customer_ip_address": "187.167.213.178",
"customer_user_agent": "okhttp/3.3.0",
"created_via": "rest-api",
"customer_note": "",
"date_completed": "2017-02-14T02:11:17",
"date_paid": "",
"cart_hash": "",
"line_items": [ ],
"tax_lines": [ ],
"shipping_lines": [ ],
"fee_lines": [ ],
"coupon_lines": [ ],
"refunds": [ ],
```

}

Changing the method parameters of the endpoint like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("orders"+ ConstantesAPI.ACCES_TOKEN)
Call<Pedido> Crearpedido(
        @Field("date_created")String date,
        @Field("customer_id") int idcliente,
        @Field("line_items[]")  ArrayList<LineItem> line_items);


EndpointsAPI pedidoapi = apiadapter.conectarRestAPI(gsonBuilder.create());
    Call<Pedido> peticionpedido = pedidoapi.Crearpedido(pedido.getDateCreated(),pedido.getCustomerId(), lineitems);
    peticionpedido.enqueue(new Callback<Pedido>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Pedido> call, Response<Pedido> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pedido de cliente:  "+ id_cliente_np +"   Realizado con Éxito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Pedido> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: el Pedido no pudo ser realizado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

And the JSON response posts correctly the "customer_id" field (5) but still missing the "line_items:" one

```
{

"id": 279,
"parent_id": 0,
"status": "pending",
"order_key": "wc_order_58a3c50135a4f",
"number": 279,
"currency": "MXN",
"version": "2.6.7",
"prices_include_tax": false,
"date_created": "2017-02-15T03:03:29",
"date_modified": "2017-02-15T03:03:29",
"customer_id": 5,
"discount_total": "0.00",
"discount_tax": "0.00",
"shipping_total": "0.00",
"shipping_tax": "0.00",
"cart_tax": "0.00",
"total": "0.00",
"total_tax": "0.00",
"billing": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": "",
    "email": "eugenio_atocpan@panaderiaelrollo.com.mx",
    "phone": ""
},
"shipping": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": ""
},
"payment_method": "",
"payment_method_title": "",
"transaction_id": "",
"customer_ip_address": "187.167.213.178",
"customer_user_agent": "okhttp/3.3.0",
"created_via": "rest-api",
"customer_note": "",
"date_completed": "2017-02-15T03:03:29",
"date_paid": "",
"cart_hash": "",
"line_items": [ ],
"tax_lines": [ ],
"shipping_lines": [ ],
"fee_lines": [ ],
"coupon_lines": [ ],
"refunds": [ ],
```

}

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you are creating empty registers, endpoint is OK. I never used Retrofit2 so it's difficult to say, but you should log your request in server side, and see how the data are send. You probably don't send well datas.

You should also debug the object Pedido before sending, in Android, to see if it is well formed.

Comment: Question Updated @JuliatzindelToro, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same GSON at the server side?
As mentioned, it could be because the following field:

```
@SerializedName("line_items")
@Expose
private ArrayList<LineItem> line_items;
```

Because you used SerializedName, the JSON serialized for this list will be:

```
{“line_items”:[..]}
```

When this JSON comes to server side, the server side may not deserialized this field because it's kind of not follow convention.

To fix this, you can:
1) Change @SerializedName("line_items") to @SerializedName("lineItems") or

2) Change line_items to lineItems to follow convention and remove the @SerializedName("line_items") or

3) Change the server code to instruct it to deserialize the "line_items" field into object property.( If server side is Java and you use Jackson at server side, add this to the line_items object: @JsonProperty("line_items").

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @NangSaigon, tryng the first suggestion the code has been edited to this:

`@SerializedName("lineitems")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<LineItem> line_items;

public ArrayList<LineItem> getLineItems() {
        return line_items;
    }


    public void setLineItems(ArrayList<LineItem> line_items) {
        this.line_items = line_items;
    }`

but still getting the same result

Comment: also tryed by changing the code to this:


`private ArrayList<LineItem> lineitems;`

but still only Posting the customer_id

Comment: lineItems, not lineitems. See this link for POJO convention: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm

Comment: OK great, are you refering to the POJO class right? thanks a lot!, shall I read it all, or is it an specific part that should be paid more atention? thanks a lot again!